# When is extending the Application class needed?

Tags: android

I saw several places and people suggesting extending the `Application` class in their app.
Personally, I have never needed the necessity to do so.

I was not able to find a clear cut and direct answer by google-ing, so here are some questions :

- What is an `application` class ?
- why do we need it ?
- Is it a singleton ? or we can have several instances ?
- When we use it inside our manifest, is it the same as using the default application that usually eclipse generates ?
- When are cases that extending it might be needed ? and when it is an overhead ?
- Is it useful for caching purposes ?

Answer (score 5):

It is something I have also thought about when I first started developing with Android and never came up with an answer. However just a quick google myself [revealed this website](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/).

Essentially I think it comes down to the fact if you are making a more involved Android application which would involve several Activity classes then things become difficult if you need to persist data that is to be shared between the various Activity classes of your application. Quoting from the above website:

> If you take a look at the Application class (see here) in the API reference guide, you get a suggestion on how to manage global application data.  The Application class, it says, is the “Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.”

If you've just started Android development this point may not be apparent to begin with however once you've worked with SDK for a while and you come up with an idea that you'd like to develop in a serious way you may hit upon this problem and then the reason for the Application class will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android documentation there is quite good explanation what the Applications.class is.

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.
>
> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

Sometimes you may need it to extend in order to work with external libraries. I did use it for UrbanAirship [see here](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android.html#configuring-your-client-application)

The Application instance is indeed one for our app and it is created when our application starts and removed when it is closed. It represents general state of the application.